# Unity3D: Баги в простейшей 2D игре

Tags: c#, unity3d

Написал недавно простую 2D игру на Unity.  Если запускать в редакторе Unity, то все нормально, а если на телефоне, то появляются фризы и неплавности при падении фруктов и передвижении птички. Tак же текст в левом верхнем углу значительно меньше чем в Unity редакторе. С чем это может быть связано. [Код](https://github.com/SamurajKing/GetFoodGame2.0)

Comment: вы предлагаете нам искать по всему вашему репозиторию проблемы в вашем коде, которые воспроизводятся только на мобильнике?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Про фризы.**
Сходу сказать сложно. Как и написано в комментарии к Вашему вопросу - изучать весь репозиторий? Приведите код, который отвечает за падение фруктов и код, который прикреплен к фруктам. Скорее всего, что-то ресурсоемкое происходит в Update.

**2. Про размер текста**
Скорее всего, если Вы текст размещаете на юнити-канве, то на объекте с Canvas нет компонента CanvasScaler.